# $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ where $f(x+f(x+y))=f(2x)+y$ for every $x,y \in\Bbb R$

Tags: functions

> Define $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ where $f(x+f(x+y))=f(2x)+y$ for every $x,y \in\Bbb R$. Prove $f(0)=0$.

Can someone help, if I use $x=y=0$ then I found $f(f(0))=f(0)$ but I cannot prove that f is one-to-one.

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: BTW, once we know $f(0)=0$, we find (let $y=-x$) that $f(x)=f(2x)-x$. With  $y=x$,  $f(x+f(2x))=x+f(2x)$, i.e. $f(2x)+x$ ($=f(x)+2x$) is a fixpoint. 
If $0$ is the only fixpoint, we conclude $f(x)=-2x$ for all $x$, but that is no solution: $f(x+f(x+y))=f(-x-2y)=2x+4y\ne-4x+y=f(2x)+y$. 
If $f(a)=a$ then $f(x+a)=f(x+f(x+a-x)) = f(2x)+a-x=f(x)+a$. In particular, if one of $x,x+a$ is a fixpoint then so is the other. The fixpoints form a non-trivial subgroup of $\Bbb R$. $x=a/2, y=-a/2$ gives us $f(\frac a2)=f(\frac a2+f(0))=f(a)-\frac a2=\frac a2$ so that fixpoints are dense in $\Bbb R$. (cont)

Comment: (cont) So  if we assume continuity, $f$ is the identity.

Answer (score 4):

Take $x=0$. Then $f(f(y)) = y+f(0)$, so in particular $f$ is surjective. Take $z$ so that $f(z) = 0$. Let $x=0$ and $y=z$ to get $f(0) = z+f(0) \implies z=0$.

Comment: This shows the desired result $f(0)=0$ without showing that $f$ is one-to-one. It turns out that $f$ must indeed be one-to-one: If $f(a)=f(b)$, then 
$a+f(0)=f(0+f(0+a))=f(0+f(0+b))=b+f(0) $
and so $a=b$.

Comment: Yes. $f(f(y)) = y+f(0)$ cleanly shows injectivity

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You might want to try just $x = 0$ and see what that tells you.

Then try just $y = 0$ and see what *that* tells you.